# How to take data from var in radio button list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I am using linQ to sql and my .cs page code is

```
var rrlist = db.sel_aut_rec(12); //stored procedure

if (rrlist.Count() != 0)
{
rblist1.DataSource = rrlist;  //radio button list
rblist1.DataTextField ="tbl1.j_title";
rblist1.DataValueField ="tbl1.ed_journal_id";
rblist1.DataBind();
}
```

and my store procedure code is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sel_aut_rec
@auth_id int
AS
 select tbl1.ed_journal_id,tbl1.j_title from tbl_aut_rec as tbl inner join editor_j_inf as tbl1 on tbl.j_id=tbl1.ed_journal_id where tbl.auth_id=@auth_id order by tbl.aut_rec_id desc

RETURN
```

I dont know how to take particular column from rrlist1 containing many rows

**my question is solved doing**

```
var rrlist = db.sel_aut_rec(12).tolist();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach should be ,

1. Change you SP and pick Id, Name or anything to identify the radio buttons uniquely.
   Assuming Auth_Id and Auth_name in you case.
2. Set the two to your list.

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sel_aut_rec
@auth_id int
AS
BEGIN

select auth_id as Id, auth_name as Name 
from tbl_aut_rec as tbl 
  inner join editor_j_inf as tbl1 
    on tbl.j_id=tbl1.ed_journal_id 
where auth_id=@auth_id order by aut_rec_id desc

END
```

CS:

```
var rrlist = db.sel_aut_rec(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["authorid"].Value); //stored procedure

if (rrlist !=null)
{
rblist1.DataSource = rrlist;  
rblist1.DataTextField =  "Id"  // You should pick Id and Name 
                               //{or whatever suits your need} so as 
                               //  to set the text and value
rblist1.DataValueField = "Name"
rblist1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: see my edited question, i've tried this and getting an error "System.InvalidOperationException: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.
" at rrlist1.databind();

Comment: @Alps : Actually Count() already enumerates once. You have to remove count(). Else you need to convert it to array using var x = rrlist.ToArray() and in if use x.Length > 0. But its not mandatory that you keep check. Its upto you.

Answer (score 0):

`select *` will get the all cloumns from your all table, So you need give a correct column name and column id for

```
rblist1.DataTextField = "ColumnName" //For display purpose like description field

rblist1.DataValueField = "ColumnName" //For storing in DB like id field name
```

Please take a look at this [sample](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-bind-data-to-radiobuttonlist-control-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1048.aspx)

Comment: see my edited question, i have tried it but the error is coming "System.InvalidOperationException: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once. "

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Linq instaid of using your stored procedure:

```
var rrlist = dbo.tbl_aut_rec.Join(dbo.editor_j_inf, a => a.j_id, e => e.ed_journal_id, (a, e) => new { Author = a, Editor e})
.Where(AuthorAndEditor => AuthorAndEditor.Author.auth_id.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["authorid"].Value))
.OrderBy(AuthorAndEditor => AuthorAndEditor.Author.aut_rec_id).ToList();

if (rrlist.Count() != 0)
{
rblist1.DataSource = rrlist;  //radio button list
rblist1.DataTextField = "Id"  //how to take particular column from rrlist1 containing many row
rblist1.DataValueField = "Name" //how to take particular column from rrlist1 containing many row
rblist1.DataBind();
}
```

I wrote it in notepad fast, so might contain a typo.

Comment: see my edited question, i've tried this and getting an error "System.InvalidOperationException: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.
" at rrlist1.databind();

Comment: Could you try to edit I made? It's been a while since I did something like this in Linq.

Comment: can you plz make this linq query into SP, so i can use it repeatedly in different page?

Comment: Does it work as expected? I would suggest using a class with this Linq query which basically enables you to do the same thing. 1> Create a static class (for example: ServiceManager.cs) 2> create a static method with a corresponding name 3> use the class in different pages from your application.